# DOM Order Of Execution Wonderings

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The order of execution of html/javascript , as far as I know , is serial (as in all programming language) , meaning the browser reads line by line of html/javascript code and interprets it .

That is why some javascript programmers put the  tag at the end of the body - to make sure the entire DOM was loaded and they can now access whatever elements they want .
This is how they do it -

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<script> //whatever code you want to put
</script>
</body>
```

I wanted to test this so I wrote the following code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var elm=document.getElementById("myp");
alert(elm.innerHTML);
</script>
<p id="myp"> well this is darned interesting </p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I've put the script before the p element is defined and the script is trying to access it . I thought I would get an error since p isn't supposed to be defined yet but I got "well this is darned interesting" (the value of p) . 
The same thing happens when I put the script in the head element. (testest with chrome and firefox).

Can anyone shed some light into what's going on ?

Comment: I've got an error on the firebug console/Fx13 as I expected: http://jsfiddle.net/x8BmK/

Comment: OK but the result is still 'well this is darned interesting' . I was just wondering what's going on in modern browsers regarding this issue...

Comment: what result? the alert is not shown at all, and the text is already part of the markup

Comment: weird . I'm on Firefox 13.0 and I see the alert , I also see it in chrome.

Comment: I don't. Here's a similar fiddle. I only get the second alert. http://jsfiddle.net/stqcV/

Comment: Okay I see what you guys mean - please forget Fiddle , create a new html file , save it and run it (using Firefox 13) . You should see what I see I am not making this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the specifics of what's going on with this particular example, I'll summarize the general principle.  My source is Flanagan, **JavaScript: The Ultimate Guide**, 5/e.

It's too simplistic to think of a browser as reading a line of HTML and rendering something in response.  Certainly it scans the input sequentially, but the sequence of DOM object construction is not line-for-line with the scanned input.  Better to treat it as a black box.

If you want to run a script that will manipulate DOM elements, the safe and sure way is to run it as a handler for the `onload` event.  Sometimes you can write inline script to do it, but this is a gray area.  Flanagan writes:

> Most browsers seem to allow scripts to manipulate any document
>   elements that appear before the `<script>` tag.  Some JavaScript
>   programmers do this routinely.  However, no standard required it to
>   work, and there is a persistent, if vague, belief among some
>   experienced JavaScript coders that placing document manipulation code
>   within `<script>` tags can cause problems.... (p. 256)

However, you may need to manipulate the DOM after all the HTML has been parsed but before all images are loaded.  If that's your need, then a tool like jQuery and its [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event is the way to go.